# How to implement users post/feed in react-native

Tags: node.js, react-native, feed

I am trying to build an app where user can follow another user and can see the post/feed done by the followed person. I am using react-native and node and google signin to create users.

When a user logs in to his/her home page, I want to display all the post/feed done by the other users whom he/she is following. How to fetch the post/feed of the followed persons? Is there any free/paid service to implement the same?

Need some idea or any kind of reference that can help to achieve the same.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using Firebase? There's a really simple denormalization pattern you can use in RTDB until you hit about 10k MAUs.

Basically you can organize your data around your read pattern so you can do something like ``` firebase.database().ref(``feeds/${userId}/``) ``` to get a followers feed.

On the write side, you have to listen for new posts to be made and then look up who subscribes to the post author, then copy the post data to their feed.

You'll end up with a RTDB that looks like this:

```
{
  posts: {
    123: { text: "hi", owner: 54 },
  },
  follows: {
    55: { follower: 44, followee: 54 },
  },
  feeds: {
    44: {
      123: { text: "hi", owner: 54 },
    },
  },
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing the details. But I am looking for solution without firebase. Any other way that provides the solution as I have been told not to use firebase. Your suggestion will be valuable.

Comment: Any good answer will change entirely depending on the scale you are designing for. How many hourly fetches from how many different users? How many average followers? What technologies are you using? Are posts and follows updated frequently? Is eventually consistency okay?

Comment: You can use the above approach where posts and follows are collections in your database and feeds is a redis set.

Comment: Ok I will try to implement the collection approach. Thank you.